# Is there a way to change a web shortcut/bookmarks icon on the desktop

Tags: shortcut, bookmarks

I was wondering if there's a way to create a web shortcut on the desktop with a icon loaded in from the such as using the FavIco.ico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the desktop and select New > Shortcut.  In the text field to "Type the location of the item" enter the url.  Once the shortcut is created, it will use an icon from the site.

If you then open this link in Notepad, you will see the "IconFile" property is set to the favicon.ico for the site.